# Emacs message function displays the message in the main window instead of echo area

Tags: emacs, elisp

From what I could find in the Emacs docs, the message function should display its message in the echo area at the bottom of the frame in Emacs.  But when I call it, it prints its message at the cursor location in the main window.  Am I doing something wrong?  How can I get it to print in the echo area instead?

Here's the code I'm using if it matters.  I'm trying to get out of the habit of using backspace and instead use backward-kill-word so I remapped backspace in my init.el:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<backspace>") (message "Don't use backspace!"))
```

Comment: You're missing `(lambda()(interactive)(message...))`

Comment: So I should use that rather than just calling message?  Why is that?

Comment: Adding `interactive` makes function into a command. Only commands can be bound to keys.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  Didn't realize that about commands and functions.  If you want to write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Note that in your original code, you are binding a key to the *return value* of `(message "Don't use backspace!")` (which was evaluated immediately, rather than when you subsequently typed the bound key). You want to use `(lambda ...)` because the return value of that is a *function*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions that can be bound to keys (i.e. called interactively) are called commands.
To make function into a command you need to add
[interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html)
to the delaration:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<backspace>")
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (message "Don't use backspace!")))
```